# Spring MVC Relative Redirect from HttpServletResponse

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Given this methodology of relative redirect to another controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/someController")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping("/redirme")
    public String processForm(ModelMap model) {            
        return "redirect:/someController/somePage";
    }
}
```

How can I simulate that same *relative* redirect given that I'm within an interceptor?

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        response.sendRedirect("/someController/somePage");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now with the interceptor, i will end up at application.com/someController/somePage when I really want to be at application.com/deployment/someController/somePage. Surely there must be a 'spring' solution for this?

Comment: Did you try `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + uri);`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Converting my comment to an answer -

Try using `response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + uri);`

Comment: Thanks for your sulation.But why when I used this way to redirect user to the same page, the model.addAttributte("error", "error") not worked? I cannot show it in the redirected page.. Do you have a any idea about this?

Comment: The servlet container will still convert it into an absolute redirect

Answer (score 1):

After referencing the [redirect documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-redirecting),reviewing the source code for UrlBasedViewResolver, and gotuskar's comment, I feel silly for not knowing this would work and have a solution:

```
public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception
    {
        StringBuilder targetUrl = new StringBuilder();
        if (this.redirectURL.startsWith("/")) {
            // Do not apply context path to relative URLs.
            targetUrl.append(request.getContextPath());
        }
        targetUrl.append(this.redirectURL);

        if(logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Redirecting to: " + targetUrl.toString());
        }

        response.sendRedirect(targetUrl.toString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As recommended by an answer to the more recent question [Context path with url-pattern redirect in spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27843540/context-path-with-url-pattern-redirect-in-spring), you could use `ServletUriComponentsBuilder`