# Context path with url-pattern redirect in spring

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I'm having a bit of a puzzle with paths and urls on a tomcat server, let me explain:

My tomcat webapp directory is: /server

I have deployed a spring application in directory /server/myapp/subfolder

This means my context path /server/myapp

My servlet has an url-pattern of /subfolder/*

My servlet can be reached at url http://server.com/myapp/subfolder/

In a many of my spring controllers i return a redirect:

```
return "redirect:/item/list";
```

This redirects the visitor to http://server.com/myapp/item/list

This of course results in a 404 cause the right url is: http://server.com/myapp/subfolder/item/list

This can easily be solved by just putting everything is a separate webapp or simply removing the url-pattern. But both aren't possible because a separate webapp means a different class-loader (causes problem with other systems) and url-pattern like / will conflict with other applications running on the server.

I can change my redirect to "redirect:/subfolder/item/list", that will fix the redirect.

Is there maybe a better solution so that i don't have to manually add "subfolder/" everywhere the contextpath is used?

Comment: See [spring-mvc-relative-redirect-from-httpservletresponse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981754/spring-mvc-relative-redirect-from-httpservletresponse)

Comment: Have you tried `return "redirect:item/list";`?

Comment: @acdcjunior spring isn't that smart :) It goes to http://server.com/myapp/subfolder/item/list/item/list which makes sense in a way.

Comment: @pmorken getContextPath doesn't include the url-pattern...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end i simply made a util function:

```
public String redirect(String path){
    return "redirect:/subfolder"+path;
}
```

Bit hacky, but it allows me to quickly change "subfolder" in case the url-pattern changes.

The @url tag in the view also uses contextpath, so i created my own @url tag which adds "subfolder" to the contextpath.

Spring now seems happy, i don't get any 404's anymore.

Comment: You might look at http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/ for a less hacky solution; seems like a combination of <rule> and <outbound-rule> would do what you want (and maybe avoid view issues as well).

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question, but if anyone is looking for the current answer, RedirectView (at least in the most recent 5.0.9 version) has a contextRelative boolean parameter that is false by default. Setting that to true makes the redirect context relative. For example:

```
return new RedirectView("/account", true);
```

Reference: [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/view/RedirectView.html)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is what I exactly searched)

Answer (score 4):

Rather than hard wiring your apps context path, you can get it from the HttpServletRequest.getContextPath().

Answer (score 4):

Spring has the `ServletUriComponentsBuilder` which you can use to your advantage. You can pass it the current request and let it append where you want to goto. Saves you hard coding the `/subfolder` or whatever you do.

```
UriComponents uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder
                            .fromServletMapping(request)
                            .fromPath("/item/list")
                            .build();
return "redirect:" + uri.toUriString();
```

Ofcourse you could put this in a utility method. This only works if you are redirecting to a URL within the same `DispatcherServlet`.

Comment: I want to give you +1 for suggesting this, but give you -1 because `.fromPath("/item/list")` cancels out `fromServletMapping(request)`. Only use one of these `from*` methods, and build up your URI using the other methods.